# Python pdfminer LAParams mixes text output

Tags: python, pdfminer

i have a pdf file and i wanna parse text from it with pdfminer.The problem is LAParams sometimes fails and give some portion of the line at the end.I can't figure out why. My pdf looks like this:
[image: pdf]
Out put looks like this:
[image: output]
My code is here,thanks in advance:

```
from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFResourceManager, PDFPageInterpreter
from pdfminer.converter import TextConverter
from pdfminer.layout import LAParams
from pdfminer.pdfpage import PDFPage
from io import StringIO

def convert_pdf_to_txt(path):
    rsrcmgr = PDFResourceManager()
    retstr = StringIO()
    codec = 'utf-8'
    laparams = LAParams()
    device = TextConverter(rsrcmgr, retstr, codec=codec , laparams=laparams)
    fp = open(path, 'rb')
    interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(rsrcmgr, device)
    password = ""
    caching = True
    pagenos=set()

    for PageNumer,page in enumerate(PDFPage.get_pages(fp, pagenos , password=password,caching=caching, check_extractable=True)):
        interpreter.process_page(page)

    text = retstr.getvalue()

    fp.close()
    device.close()
    retstr.close()
    return text
print(convert_pdf_to_txt('C:\\Users\\Vagos\\Desktop\\europe.pdf'))
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Found the answer myself.

#### Issue

The layout-analysis parameters [`LAParams()`](https://pdfminersix.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/composable.html#laparams) (docs for `pdfminer.six`) default to `word_margin` of `0.1`:

> class `pdfminer.layout.LAParams`(line_overlap: float = 0.5, char_margin: float = 2.0, line_margin: float = 0.5, **word_margin: float = 0.1**, boxes_flow: Optional[float] = 0.5, detect_vertical: bool = False, all_texts: bool = False)

For inactive `pdfminer` see source code of [`LAParams()`](https://github.com/euske/pdfminer/blob/master/pdfminer/layout.py#L39).

My document apparently sometimes had greater word-margins which caused the problems.

#### Solution

Using `LAParams(char_margin = 20)` which initiates the `char_margin` with 20 solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

The LAParams() is what tells your code how to group together the different characters in your file. Playin with the char_margin, line margin and all_texts parameters is a good start to start fine tuning the processing of your file.

The containers for your file are being computed using the relative distance between the different components (the chars, the lines of text and so on).

The documentation on GitHub for the layout.py is particularly helpful (https://github.com/pdfminer/pdfminer.six/blob/master/pdfminer/layout.py#L748)

```
class LTLayoutContainer(LTContainer[LTComponent]):
    def __init__(self, bbox: Rect) -> None:
        LTContainer.__init__(self, bbox)
        self.groups: Optional[List[LTTextGroup]] = None
        return

    # group_objects: group text object to textlines.
    def group_objects(self, laparams: LAParams, objs: Iterable[LTComponent]) -> Iterator[LTTextLine]:
        obj0 = None
        line = None
        for obj1 in objs:
            if obj0 is not None:
                # halign: obj0 and obj1 is horizontally aligned.
                #
                #   +------+ - - -
                #   | obj0 | - - +------+   -
                #   |      |     | obj1 |   | (line_overlap)
                #   +------+ - - |      |   -
                #          - - - +------+
                #
                #          |<--->|
                #        (char_margin)
```